# C# Check if Regex is a match, returns True instead of False

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

I'm not familiar with Regex so, I hope someone can help me with this. I'm using Regex and I'm checking further in the code if that specific Regex is a match or not.

Regex I use and want to check for:

- `Regex InitialGForKj = new Regex("[Y[\s\S]|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]]", RegexOptions.Compiled);`.

Now the code where I check if it is a match is as followed:

```
else if (i == 0 && InitialGForKj.IsMatch(upperLetters.Substring(1, 3)))
        {
            dmetaphoneKeyResultPrimary.Append("K");
            dmetaphoneKeyResultSecondary.Append("J");
            i += 2;
        }
```

- `i` is the current Character (In this case it is 'G').
- `upperLetters` = The Word what will be checked (In this case: Garçon).
- `dmetaphoneKeyResultPrimary` and `dmetaphoneKeyResultSecondary` are the replacements for the Letter 'G' (Both are Stringbuilders).

I Also checked with `Console.WriteLine()` what the substring its value is (Which returns "arç").
So, now the question is, why does the code see this as `true` and not as `False`? Which I think it must be `False`.

Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: `[Y[\s\S]|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]]` looks weird: it seems you tried to use an alternation construct within a character class, which is not possible. Can explain further what you're trying to match, some examples of checked input, result and what you were expected when it went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must write it as

```
var InitialGForKj = new Regex("Y.|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Y.%7cE%5bBILPRSY%5d%7cI%5bBELN%5d&i=ar%c3%a7%0d%0aY%3b%0d%0aEB%0d%0aIE&o=sm). Note that `.` matches any char including a newline since the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option is passed to the *Regex* constructor.

The current `[Y[\s\S]|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]]` pattern matches 3 alternatives:

- `[Y[\s\S]` - a `Y`, `[`, whitespace or non-whitespace (this matches any char there is!)
- `|` - or
- `E[BILPRSY]` - `E` and then one letter from the class
- `|` - or
- `I[BELN]]` - a `I` followed with `B`, `E`, `L`, `N`,  and then `]`.

As you see, you corrupted it by enclosing the whole pattern with `[` and `]`.

Comment: @RaymonJansen I am just a bit puzzled with `.Substring(1, 3)` now: the regex must match 3 chars, right? If you use a version with anchors, it will only match a 2-char string. Shall I remove the version with anchors? You are using `@"Y[\s\S]|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]"`, right?

Comment: Well I was trying to translate this:

        `/* -ges-, -gep-, -gel- at beginning. */
        if ( index === 0 &&  INITIAL_G_FOR_KJ.test(value.slice(1, 3))) 
          {
              primary += 'K';
              secondary += 'J';
              index += 2;
          }`

Comment: @RaymonJansen Ok, got it: the `String.Substring` in C# accepts the length as the second argument, not the end position, as in [`arr.slice(begin, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), so you most probably need to use `upperLetters.Substring(1, 2)` and use the version with anchors. Although both patterns should work for this scenario. If you need to expand the pattern later to include longer alternatives, make sure longer alternatives come first in an unanchored pattern.

Comment: Well, it works now, I'm not that great at programming yet and I had to translate al lot of code from `Java` to `C#`, I'm now using: `Regex InitialGForKj = new Regex("Y[\\s\\S]|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]", RegexOptions.Compiled);`.

Trying to make DoubleMetaphone, so I don't think it will change later on.

Comment: @RaymonJansen It is better to use a built-in functionality to let `.` match any char: `var InitialGForKj = new Regex("Y.|E[BILPRSY]|I[BELN]", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);` , I updated the answer with the final pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is your current expression:

[image]

As you see, the outer [ ] will be recognized as chars. So drop them!

Because \s\S is recognised as whitespace or non-whitespace, so pretty much as everything, Garcon is a valid match.